# jQuery - get the index of <input> throwing a keypress event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, indexing

I'm trying to get the index of an input between a set of inputs. Basically, I have a table that contains, on more than one row, many inputs.

Once the user press the "enter" button, while the input is focused, I need to jump to the next input field, as the "tab" key do.

I was following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335553/jquery-how-to-catch-enter-key-and-change-event-to-tab) accepted response, and this is what I've done so far: **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5DwHw/)**

**CODE**

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
    if( e.which == 13 && e.target.nodeName == 'INPUT'){
        var inputs = $("#inputsTable input.td_in");
        alert(inputs.index(this));
    }
});
```

as you can see, every time you focus an input and then press ENTER, the popup msg says "-1"..

What am I doing wrong? I've been struggling with this piece of code for an hour, and I'm giving up.

---

I found out that replacing `this` with `e.target` also works.

**CODE**

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
    if( e.which == 13 && e.target.nodeName == 'INPUT'){
        var inputs = $("#inputsTable input.td_in");
        alert(inputs.index(e.target));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `this` references the `document`, not your `input`.

Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), and pass it an `input.td_in` selector:

```
$('#inputsTable').on('keypress', 'input.td_in', function (e) {
    if( e.which == 13 ) {
        var inputs = $("#inputsTable input.td_in");
        alert(inputs.index(this));
    }
});
```

**P.S.** You should probably [cache that selector](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-jquery-newbs-stop-jumping-in-the-pool/).

Comment: thanks for your reply! I've found out that also using "e.target" instead of "this" works for my example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('keypress', 'input', function (e) {
    if( e.which == 13 ){
        var inputs = $("#inputsTable input");
        var the_index = inputs.index(this);        
        inputs[the_index+1].focus();
    }    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5DwHw/1/