# Enter is a click in a field in a form

Tags: jquery, html, forms, button, textfield

For some reason, if you have a `button` in a form, and a `text field` in a `form`, pressing enter when the `text field` has focus results in the `button` being clicked.

http://jsfiddle.net/cZcGE/

Why does this happen, and how do I make it (the `text field`) act in a more predictable manner (pressing enter in the `text field` counts as a `keyup` event)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335553/jquery-how-to-catch-enter-key-and-change-event-to-tab - Check that out. Verify the captured event's key code is 13 (enter key) and then do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Thanks, but it really doesn't look like that has anything to do with my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pressing enter in a form is going to attempt to press a button/submit the form. As mentioned in the comments, if you don't want that behavior, you have to capture the keypress and prevent the submission if it was the enter key that was pressed.

In your case, it would be adding this bit of code:

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('keypress', function (event) {
    if(event.which == 13){
        return false;
    }
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/cZcGE/8/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a button, it might be better to use an input with button-type.

http://jsfiddle.net/cZcGE/

```
<form>
    <input type="button" value="bla" />
    <input type="text" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/cZcGE/9/)**

Try this,
add `onkeydown = "return (event.keyCode!=13);"` to the `textbox`

```
<input type="text" onkeydown = "return (event.keyCode!=13);"></input>
```

Hope this helps,Thank you