# How to make the enter key do the tab key function for form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown, jquery-hotkeys

I am using jQuery Hotkey plugin https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys , I want to move to other input boxes on keydown Enter instead of Tab which is default behaviour. But somehow I can't make it go. Can anyone please help me how to sort that, basically with custom javascript I can do but since I have maximum events fired on this plugin and with " Enter event" I am not trying to use that.

For other events I am just adding a part of the code:

```
$("#bca").bind('keydown', 'return', function(e){
    var pickerVal = $("#enterMe").val();
    var picked2Val = $("#bca").val();
     $("#enterMe").attr("value",pickerVal );
     $("#bca").attr("value",picked2Val );
    //$("#abc").html( pickerVal );
    //alert(pickerVal);

    if( picked2Val == pickerVal ){ alert("equal")} else { alert("not equal")}


   });
```

Anyone's help is highly appreciated
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery how to catch enter key and change event to tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335553/jquery-how-to-catch-enter-key-and-change-event-to-tab)