# IE 11 loses tabindex on blur

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, accessibility, internet-explorer-11, tabindex

When I trigger a blur event on an input, button or select element chrome and firefox keep the current tabindex. If I press tab again after the blur event fired, the browser will focus the next input correctly.

IE11 however loses the tabindex completely, and starts at the beginning of the page.

**Example: (run in chrome and IE11 for testing):**

Focus any input and press enter => blur.
Press tab. Chrome and FF will focus the next input after the last tabindex.
IE will focus the first input element on the page.

https://jsfiddle.net/4wnt0o44/1/

HTML:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" length="30" />
  <input type="text" length="30" />
  <input type="text" length="30" />
  <input type="text" length="30" />
  <input type="text" length="30" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
document.body.addEventListener('keypress', function(event){
    if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input') {
      const keyCode = event.which || event.keyCode;

      if (keyCode === 13) {
        event.target.blur()
      }
  }
})
```

Are there any known workarounds for this problem?

Comment: Surely if someone presses enter, the form will be submitted so this isn't going to be a problem?

Comment: enter was just used for the example. It's about the blur event that resets IEs current tabindex

Comment: If you're not opposed to using jQuery, there's a pretty good solution here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335553/jquery-how-to-catch-enter-key-and-change-event-to-tab

Comment: @Pete that must be one of the hackiest things I have ever seen..

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you managed to solve it?

Comment: @dude no, I am still looking for a solution