# dispatchEvent in Angular 5 on input element for key Tab not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I read many post how to move from one input to another on `Enter` keypress. Many contains solution with custom directive which is not good, because I want that this works out of the box (without implementing directive on every component).

I simply try to call `dispatchEvent` with key `Tab`. But it is not working. It seems so simple. I really hope I am not doing something stupid and someone can explain to me, why **[this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u2dsbv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)** doesn't work.

```
<input (keyup)="handleChange($event)">

 public handleChange(e: KeyboardEvent)
 {
    if (e && e.keyCode === 13)
    {
      e.srcElement.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: '9' }));
      e.srcElement.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress', { key: '9' }));
      e.srcElement.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup', { key: '9' }));

      e.target.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: '9' }));
      e.target.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress', { key: '9' }));
      e.target.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup', { key: '9' }));


      e.srcElement.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { code: '9' }));
      e.srcElement.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress', { code: '9' }));
      e.srcElement.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup', { code: '9' }));

      e.target.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { code: '9' }));
      e.target.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress', { code: '9' }));
      e.target.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup', { code: '9' }));

      e.srcElement.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: 'Tab' }));
      e.srcElement.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress', { key: 'Tab' }));
      e.srcElement.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup', { key: 'Tab' }));

      e.target.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: 'Tab' }));
      e.target.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress', { key: 'Tab' }));
      e.target.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup', { key: 'Tab' }));


      e.srcElement.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { code: 'Tab' }));
      e.srcElement.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress', { code: 'Tab' }));
      e.srcElement.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup', { code: 'Tab' }));

      e.target.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { code: 'Tab' }));
      e.target.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress', { code: 'Tab' }));
      e.target.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup', { code: 'Tab' }));

      console.log("Should move. Event was dispatched on", e.target, e.srcElement);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is late by 3 years, but maybe it'll help someone save hours of searching...

### It won't work.

Looks like **focusing is not possible with `dispatchEvent`**. The simulated <kbd>Tab</kbd> key is not interpreted the same as when it's pressed by the user, so it doesn't change the focus.

### So what do I do?

You could write a function that looks for the next (or previous) tabbable element and calls `focus()` on it. Note that "tabbable" is not the same as "focusable" – elements with `tabindex="-1"` can be focused programmatically with `focus()`, but they can't be tabbed to by the user. [Read more about tabbable vs. focusable.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7871725)

Alternatively, you can use an existing solution, like [Joel Purra's EmulateTab](https://github.com/joelpurra/emulatetab/blob/master/src/emulatetab.joelpurra.js). Unfortunately it's in jQuery, but the core idea is the same: find the proper element and call `focus()`.