# Disable TAB key for all controls in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, tabindex

I have an asp.net MVC project with multiple pages. 
For each page I must set the TAB key to go only among some controls. I know I can set:

```
tabIndex=x , x > 0 //to enable
tabIndex=-1, //to disable
```

The problem is that I have 5 controls for which the TAB key should work and 50 controls for which it should not work (the numbers are just to understand the proportions). So I was wondering if there is a way to disable the TAB key for an entire page (from *.css or a manager) and than make it enable just for the few specific controls that need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this cannot be done as directly as you probably hope. What you can consider doing is executing a JS function on all elements where the tab index not set, setting it to less than zero:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("input:not([tabindex])");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].tabindex = -1;
}
```

Keep in mind that depending on the number of elements that you have, this could be a drag on performance so you will want to consider benchmarking.

The other option that you could consider would be to create an HTML helper server-side which disables the tab index of the element. You can do helpers locally using the Razor `@helper` syntax, or globally using an extension method on the HtmlHelper class. This would perform significantly better than JS but may be a bit heavy handed depending on your scenario.

Comment: Please let me know if they help/what you end up implementing :)

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer, I implemented the first solution you proposed, but as you said I had performance problems., so I ended up implementing another solution. I will put also the solution I choose, I am not sure is the best, but it works:)

Answer (score 0):

Since there were so many elements that should not be tabbed, instead or disabling TAB key for them, I changed the default behavior for the elements that had tabIndex, onkey pressed:

1) I took all elements that have tabIndex bigger than 0:

```
var tabbables = document.querySelectorAll("input[tabindex], textarea[tabindex]");
```

this is a simplified version, you should do visibility checks and select also other types of elements (e.g. buttons, etc.)

2)  I replaced the default behavior in 2 cases: TAB presssed and the last element with tab index is selected or SHIFT+TAB is pressed and first element is selected. For these cases I forced the focus on the first element, respectively on the last element.

A similar question with a very good answer (not the accepted answer, the answer with most votes) is here: ["Focus Next Element In Tab Index"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208161/focus-next-element-in-tab-index)