# how to make a loop automatically tab everytime it runs through javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm making a code in javascript right now its really beyond simple but I honestly know nothing about javascript i've been learning for maybe 4 days. so basically I just need a while loop that presses tab every time it loops.

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events) will help you

Comment: @5austen Please elaborate your question. If possible add a code, which will help to understand the query.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by "pressing tab" every time it loops? Insert a tab character? Advance focus to the next element?

Comment: im trying to advance focus.

Comment: oh hey thanks that solves the problem i guess i should have looked harder

Answer (score 0):

[Focus Next Element In Tab Index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7208161/1059070) provides code for advancing focus to the next tabIndexed element.

Or if you're not using tabindex, then it would simply be the next [focusable area](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#focusable-area)

Exactly which elements qualify to be focusable areas appears to be platform dependent although there is a recommended list:

> Modulo platform conventions, it is suggested that for the following
>   elements, the tabindex focus flag be set:
>
> - a elements that have an href attribute
> - link elements that have an href attribute
> - button elements
> - input elements whose type attribute are not in the Hidden state
> - select elements
> - textarea elements
> - menuitem elements
> - Elements with a draggable attribute set, if that would enable the user agent to allow the user to begin a drag operations for those elements without the use of a pointing device
> - Editing hosts
> - Browsing context containers
> - Sorting interface th elements

Here's some good general information regarding focus: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#focus