# Deselect after focus

Tags: javascript

I am switching between different projects by on change event on select element. I am getting them from DB. But before loading different project i have to store name of previous one.For that i am using on focus event.

How can i then deselect my select element?

> document.getElementById("selectProject").selected = false;

is not working.

```
 var whichProjectToSave;

    function onFocusSelectProject(){
    //for saveJsonF();
    whichProjectToSave=document.getElementById("selectProject").value;
    }


function callSettingswindow(){       
 saveJsonF();
 canvas.clear();
 getJsonF();////////////////////////////////////                              
 document.getElementById("selectProject").selected = false;   
}    
document.getElementById("selectProject").onchange= callSettingswindow;
```

To make it clear: How to deselect "select" element after change is performed?

Comment: Maybe `focus` on a different element.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18749853/5894241) might help.

Comment: It will take as solution just to redirect focus on other element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of any methods that will let you "de-focus" from an element. But you could focus on any other element - as a result the select element will lose focus.

You could make use of jQuery if you wanted to programmatically focus on the element with next tab index. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208161/focus-next-element-in-tab-index/18749853#18749853) for more details.