# Enter key to move to next element in Ionic 4 Angular 8 form

Tags: angular, ionic3, ionic4, angular8, keyup

In my PWA built with Ionic and Angular 8, I am in need to handle enter key press to move to next element. How can I achieve it with (keyup.enter). Please help me.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-3drfby

Comment: Please add the relevant code as code blocks. This question would become completely useless if (when) the link dies. A Stackblitz is awesome!! :) but questioin **itself** should provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

one way is to setting a reference of the next element. like below

```
<ion-content padding>
 <form (ngSubmit)="logForm()">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Todo1</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="todo.title1" name="title1" #a (keyup.enter)="setFocus(b)"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Todo2</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="todo.title2" name="title2" #b (keyup.enter)="setFocus(c)"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Todo3</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="todo.title3" name="title3" #c (keyup.enter)="setFocus(d)"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Description</ion-label>
        <ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="todo.description" name="description" #d></ion-textarea>
      </ion-item>
      <button ion-button type="submit" block>Add Todo</button>
    </form>
</ion-content>
```

and in `.ts` file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
todo = {}
  logForm() {
    console.log(this.todo)
  }

  setFocus(nextElement) {
     nextElement.setFocus(); //For Ionic 4
    //nextElement.focus(); //older version
  }

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for elements ion-input/textarea etc.

When you are using basic input elements, even in ionic 4+ it's necessary to use the older way nextElement.focus(). 

I resolved that by using try/catch statement, and when an error happens, I called the next Element.focus();

Answer (score 6):

I would write a custom directive for this. Insipired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29883167/6294072). The directive could be placed on the formtag, we use `HostListener` to listen to `keyup.enter` and if a next element exist, we move the focus to it.

We would need to make some changes on how your form is submitted, since `ngSubmit` would be called each time you press enter. So I would remove that from the form tag, set the button to `type="button"` and instead attach click event to it to call `logForm()`.

So all in all this is what I do:

```html
<form focusDir>
<!-- .... -->
<button ion-button type="button" block (click)="logForm()">Add Todo</button>
```

The directive:

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: "[focusDir]"
})
export class FocusDirective {
  constructor() {}

  @HostListener("keyup.enter") onKeyupEnter() {
    var nextEl = this.findNextTabStop(document.activeElement);
    nextEl.focus();
    // or try for ionic 4:
    // nextEl.setFocus();
  }

  findNextTabStop(el) {
    var universe = document.querySelectorAll(
      "input, button, select, textarea, a[href]"
    );
    var list = Array.prototype.filter.call(universe, function(item) {
      return item.tabIndex >= "0";
    });
    var index = list.indexOf(el);
    return list[index + 1] || list[0];
  }
}
```

Then mark this directive in the `declarations` array in your ngModule.

**[STACKBLIZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-f5efyb?file=pages/home/home.html)**