# Tab behavior with "editor: 'list'" doesn't honor the tabindex

Tags: javascript, tabulator

Tabulator's "editor: 'list'" seems to not honor the tabindex when you press 'Tab' when the select list menu is open.

https://jsfiddle.net/sv95rzy4/3/

To reproduce in the jsfiddle click on 'Alice' in the table then press the 'Tab' key. The menu opens in the Level column. Then press the 'Tab' key again. I would expect the button in the Action column to be selected, but instead the next row's dropdown menu opens.

Here is the code if you can't see the jsfiddle for some reason. I don't *think* it has anything to do with the fact I am using a formatter for the editor list, but I left it in the example just in case. (If you comment out the formatter the behavior is still the same).

```
var tableData = [{
    name: "Alice", level: "2", actions: "<button tabindex='0' onclick=\"alert('clicked 1')\">X</button>"},
  { name: "Bob", level: "3", actions: "<button tabindex='0' onclick=\"alert('clicked 2')\">X</button>", },
];

var levels = {  1: 'Pro',  2: 'Advanced',  3: 'Moderate',  4: 'Rookie'
};

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  height: '100px',
  data: tableData,
  columns: [{
    title: "Name",
    field: "name"
  },{
    title: "Level",
    field: "level",
    editor: "list",
    editorParams: {
      values: levels
    },
    formatter: function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered) {
      var select = document.createElement('select');
      select.style.width = '100%';
      select.innerHTML = '<option>' + levels[cell.getValue()] + '</option>'; 

      return select;
    }
  }, {title: "Actions", field: "actions", formatter: 'html'} ],
});
```

Comment: I have found that if I add `keybindings: false` to the table definition then I CAN get it to behave correctly using TAB. However, SHIFT+TAB won't go to the previous row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured it out!

To fix forward tab movement you just need to add `keybindings:false` to the table definition.

To fix backward tab movement (shift+tab) you need to do a few things. I *think* this is broken because the dynamically created `input` element for the dropdown editor causes some issue with the browsers tab/focus list.

1. Add a listener to the relevant column. To make this easy I added a `cssClass` property to the column definition to ensure the listener would only see this column.

```
},{
    title: "Level",
    field: "level",
    editor: "list",
    cssClass: "customClassName",
    editorParams: {
      values: levels
    },

...

var elts = document.getElementsByClassName("tabulator-cell customClassName");
for(let i=0; i < elts.length; ++i) {
    elts[i].addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        if(e.key === 'Tab' && e.shiftKey) {
            e.preventDefault();
            focusPrevElement();
        }
    }
}
```

2. Use a slightly modified version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35173443/3487491) to create a "focusPrevElement()" function:

```
function focusPrevElement () {
    //TODO: Change this based on what is in your layout:
    var focussableElements = 'button, img, input, select, .customClassName';
    if (document.activeElement) {
        var focussable = Array.prototype.filter.call(document.querySelectorAll(focussableElements),
        function (element) {
            //check for visibility while always include the current activeElement 
            return element.offsetWidth > 0 || element.offsetHeight > 0 || element === document.activeElement
        });
        var index = focussable.indexOf(document.activeElement);
        if(index > 0) {
           // -2 is needed because of the dynamically created 'input' by Tabulator's cell editor module.
           var prevElement = focussable[index - 2] || focussable[0];
           prevElement.focus();
        }                    
    }
}
```