# Autofocus following tabindex and skip disabled fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, disable, autofocus

How does the cursor automatically hops to the next possible (not disabled) input field according to tabindex?

**I got that function (source: [Focus Next Element In Tab Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208161/focus-next-element-in-tab-index) ) but my cursor doesn't move automatically after input of 1 value: - Why?**

```
function focusNextElement () {
//add all elements we want to include in our selection
var focussableElements = 'a:not([disabled]), button:not([disabled]), input[type=text]:not([disabled]), [tabindex]:not([disabled]):not([tabindex="-1"])';
if (document.activeElement && document.activeElement.form) {
    var focussable = Array.prototype.filter.call(document.activeElement.form.querySelectorAll(focussableElements),
    function (element) {
        //check for visibility while always include the current activeElement 
        return element.offsetWidth > 0 || element.offsetHeight > 0 || element === document.activeElement
    });
    var index = focussable.indexOf(document.activeElement);
    if(index > -1) {
       var nextElement = focussable[index + 1] || focussable[0];
       nextElement.focus();
    }                    
}
}
```

Example for my input fields:

```
<table>
<thead></thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td> 1<input type="text" maxlength="1" oninput="focusNextElement(this)" id="a" name="a" tabeindex="1">.   </td>
 <td>3<input type="text" maxlength="1" oninput="focusNextElement(this)" id="b" name="b" tabeindex="3" disabled></td>
 <td>5<input type="text" maxlength="1" oninput="focusNextElement(this)" id="c" name="c" tabeindex="5"></td></tr>
 <tr>
 <td>2 <input type="text" maxlength="1" oninput="focusNextElement(this)" id="d" name="d" tabeindex="2"></td>
 <td>4<input type="text" maxlength="1" oninput="focusNextElement(this)" id="e" name="e" tabeindex="4"></td>
 <td>6<input type="text" maxlength="1" oninput="focusNextElement(this)" id="f" name="f"  tabeindex="6""></td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Example on: https://jsfiddle.net/rydjnzkw/4/

Comment: Where do you call `focusNextElement` method?

Comment: Should I do like: <input type="text" onclick = "focusNextElement()" maxlength="1" id="a"  tabindex="600" name="a"> That doesn't work also :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't most of this code, just `querySelector` the inputs which are not disabled, try to find the current element index in this array, and `focus` the next element.

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input:not([disabled])')

function focusNextElement (input) {
  const nextIndex = [...inputs].findIndex(i => i === input) + 1
  if (inputs[nextIndex]) {
    inputs[nextIndex].focus()
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="1" oninput="focusNextElement(this)" id="a" name="a">
<input type="text" maxlength="1" id="c" name="b" disabled>
<input type="text" maxlength="1" oninput="focusNextElement(this)" id="d" name="c">
```

**UPDATE**

To make it work according to `tabeindex`

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input:not([disabled])');
let focusableElement;
let maxTries = 100;
let counter = 0;
const getNextElement = (tabeindex) => {
  const element = document.querySelector(`[tabeindex="${tabeindex + 1}"]`)
  if (counter >= maxTries) {
    return;
  }
  if (element && !element.disabled) {
    counter = 0;
    focusableElement = element;
    return;
  }
  counter++
  getNextElement(tabeindex + 1)
}

function focusNextElement (input) {
  const nextIndex = [...inputs].findIndex(i => i === input) + 1
  const tabeindex= +input.getAttribute('tabeindex');
  const element = getNextElement(tabeindex)
  focusableElement.focus()
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead></thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
 <td> 1<input type="text" maxlength="1" oninput="focusNextElement(this)" id="a" name="a" tabeindex="1"></td>
 <td>3<input type="text" maxlength="1" oninput="focusNextElement(this)" id="b" name="b" tabeindex="3" disabled></td>
 <td>5<input type="text" maxlength="1" oninput="focusNextElement(this)" id="c" name="c" tabeindex="5">
</td></tr>
<tr>
 <td>2 <input type="text" maxlength="1" oninput="focusNextElement(this)" id="d" name="d" tabeindex="2"></td>
 <td>4<input type="text" maxlength="1" oninput="focusNextElement(this)" id="e" name="e" tabeindex="4"></td>
 <td>6<input type="text" maxlength="1" oninput="focusNextElement(this)" id="f" name="f"  tabeindex="6""></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! For disabled fields it works great! For the example above it worked if tabindex is not important. I updated the post with a mixed tabindex. The tabindex is upmost important. It doesn't follow the tabindex for now. Please check the following example: jsfiddle.net/rydjnzkw/4

Comment: Also, just to notify, it's not called `tabeindex` it's [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex), you can edit the name if you typo. I designed the code with `tabeindex` same as your code for compatibility

Comment: Thank you so much Mina! That code is absolutely perfect!

Comment: One additional question: How to change your function that the cursor autofocus after the user insert a number with 2 digits. So I set maxlength="2" for input field. And what do I change at your function?