# Can JavaScript emulate "press tab to jump between links" in a web page? Specifically the "highlightning" of the selected element

Tags: javascript, focus, highlight

Most browsers support "press tab to jump to the next link (?)". The selected element usually gets highlighted. This is how it looks here on SE

[image]

If I press tab now it changes to this:

[image]

Can you emulate this using JavaScript? I want to do something like

```
document.getElementById('answer-sort-dropdown-select-menu').click();
```

but instead of `click` it should be `select`/`highlight`/`focus` etc.

You can emulate this by right clicking on an element and the press tab - then the next element (not the one you right clicked but the following) is highlighted.

Tried to google this but I don't know what it is called.

---

**Update: Please note that I am not interested in the actual tab order, I am only interested in highlighting an element.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Focus Next Element In Tab Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208161/focus-next-element-in-tab-index)

Comment: @ControlAltDel No, but the answer below does - if I can get it to work. See my comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the focus() method:

```js
document.getElementById("focusButton").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("myTextField").focus();
});
```

```html
<input id="myTextField" value="Text field." />
<button id="focusButton">Click to set focus on the text field</button>
```

As shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus).

Comment: I have tried this from the browser console `document.getElementById("headerMenu").focus({ focusVisible: true })` but nothing happens (in Chrome). I was expecting the element to be highlighted? I don't need to add an event listener if I just execute it from the console, do I?