# How to convert enter key press to tab key press, without submitting form

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, form-submit

I try to convert enter key press to tab without submitting form, but just can remove submitting form pressing enter...

The view:

```
 <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="tipoContacto1" name="tipoContacto1" class="form-control input-sm" onkeypress="removerEnter(event)"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="nomeContacto1" name="nomeContacto1" class="form-control input-sm" onkeypress="removerEnter(event)"/></td>
```

The script:

```
function removerEnter(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        //$(e).target.nextSibling;
        //$(this).next('input').focus();

        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want change the default functionality of enter key?

Comment: yes, my client wants a form like excel

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009808/enter-key-press-behaves-like-a-tab-in-javascript

Comment: using this?
`if(event.keyCode==13){event.keyCode=9; return event.keyCode}` ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do by the following javascript which are as under:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input").not($(":button")).keypress(function (evt) {
            if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
                iname = $(this).val();
                if (iname !== 'Submit') {
                    var fields = $(this).parents('form:eq(0),body').find('button, input, textarea, select');
                    var index = fields.index(this);
                    if (index > -1 && (index + 1) < fields.length) {
                        fields.eq(index + 1).focus();
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Don't use `onkeypress()` function just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
iname = $(this).val();
if (iname !== 'Submit')..
```

better use

```
itype = $(this).attr('type');
if (itype !== 'submit')..
```

because val() returns the content of the input-field. Type 'Submit' and the content is submitted on enter.