# Use Enter as Tab with knockout binding and KendoUI dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, binding, knockout.js, kendo-ui

I have a page that uses KendoUI controls with knockout binding, and I need to use Enter instead of Tab to navigate through controls.

I managed to make it work great by using the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009808/enter-key-press-behaves-like-a-tab-in-javascript/15960291?noredirect=1#comment31488742_15960291) by [Damien Sawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/494635/damien-sawyer) and enhancing it with Shift-Enter as suggested by [Andre Van Zuydam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/714905/andre-van-zuydam)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.nextFieldOnEnter = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        j$(element).on('keydown', 'input, select', function (e) {
            var self = j$(this)
                , form = j$(element)
                , focusable
                , next
            ;
            var tabElements = 'input,a,select,button,textarea';
            if (e.shiftKey) {
                if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                    focusable = form.find(tabElements).filter(':visible');
                    prev = focusable.eq(focusable.index(this) - 1);

                    if (prev.length) {
                        prev.focus();
                    } else {
                        form.submit();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                focusable = form.find(tabElements).filter(':visible');
                var nextIndex = focusable.index(this) === focusable.length - 1 ? 0 : focusable.index(this) + 1;
                next = focusable.eq(nextIndex);
                next.focus();
                return false;
            }
        });
    } };
```

(my code uses j$ instead of $ for jquery because the project uses also mootools and I redefined jquery as j$)

However, I have a problem with kendoUI DropDown lists. The problem it is not  or  element, so it does not get focus (instead it is a span with special classes and unselecteable="on" attribute).

How should I update the ko binding code to set focus to dropdown on Enter?  It works with Tab

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you'll need to customize it a bit for the Kendo drop down. Can you post what your code looks like currently, maybe create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to do it. I updated the post with the code and link to original answer where I got the solution from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing the best I can without having a Kendo sample I can test this out on, but I think you should be able to achieve this. When Kendo creates a dropdown, as you said it adds a bunch of other elements and isn't given focus the same way as a regular select element. You can find a kendo select, however, by first finding its parent span with the class of `k-dropdown`.

Try adding `k-dropdown` to `tabElements` as a class selector:

```
var tabElements = 'input,a,select,button,textarea,.k-dropdown';
```

Then, adjust the part where you give focus by adding a condition to check for Kendo dropdown. So instead of just this:

```
prev.focus();
```

Try something like this:

```
if (prev.hasClass('k-dropdown')) {
    prev.children('select').first().data("kendoDropDownList").focus();
} else {
    prev.focus();
}
```