# Adding multiple filters to jquery find

Tags: jquery, html

I am extending [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009808/enter-key-press-behaves-like-a-tab-in-javascript/20099093#20099093).
I have this following code:

```
form.find('input,a,select').filter(':visible')
```

How can I add filter to remove disabled input fields and having tabindex greater than 0? So far I have tried combining with `.not(':disabled') and .not('input[tabindex>"0"]')`, but those are not working.

Comment: `form.find('input,a,select').filter(':visible').not(':disabled')` should work

Comment: so try `form.find('input,a,select').filter(':visible').not(':disabled').filter(function () {
    return this.tabIndex > 0
})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `not()` filter should work... but for tabIndex you will have to write a custom filter like

```
form.find('input,a,select').filter(':visible').filter(function () {
    return this.tabIndex > 0
}).not(':disabled')
```

---

Another way to do the same is

```
form.find('input,a,select').filter(function () {
    return this.tabIndex > 0 && $(this).is(':visible:not(:disabled)')
})
```