# HTML Button with functional nested input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `<button>` element which adds an element to my page when clicked.

What I'd like to do is to have an `<input>` inside this button, in which I could input a number, and then on button click, it would add x times the element instead of clicking x times on the `<button>`

See demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/MWxgb/5

The problem is that I can't click inside the `<input>` element inside the button, it clicks the button instead.

Is there a way to avoid this behavior ?

Comment: That's certainly interesting. FWIW, the input element doesn't render at all in IE9.

Comment: That's weird, it renders correctly on IE7 (all squared, but it renders)

Comment: Thrd: Switching to IE7 or IE8 mode causes the input to show up. I suspect nesting an input field inside a button might be non-standard, but that'd require looking at the spec. :)

Comment: Thrd: Yup, looks like it's illegal HTML to have interactive content descended from a `button`. Consider using a `div` or some other method to accomplish your goal. - http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-button-element.html#the-button-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/3vtTv/2/

I changed the button to a `div`, but still use `$("#btn").button()` to style it.

Then I call `stopPropagation` on the click event for the `#count` click handler.

This seems to work (in IE9, Chrome 10, FF4), but unfortunately the button still flashes when you click the textbox. Not sure how to work around that.

Comment: The button flashing is not a real problem. Thanks for this solution !

Answer (score 2):

Just prevent the clicks on the `<input>` from bubbling:

```
$("#count")
    .click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qT7gC/

Comment: It keeps clicking the button instead of focusing the input with IE7 and FF4

Comment: well, nesting an input in a button is invalid HTML. so it's not a very good idea to use it...

Comment: since you are using jQuery UI's button() for the button, why don't you get rid of the <button> and use a div instead? See http://jsfiddle.net/x4RYs/

Answer (score 0):

Odd idea, I doubt that would work.  I would recommend just using a text input, and setting up some javascript to read a click/enter key pressed.
Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905222/javascriptenter-key-press-event)

Here is [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/mazzzzz/3Dptk/3/)

Comment: it's functionnal, but it's not "eye candy" enough :p

Comment: That is why I usually don't do javascript, but php.  Functionality is all I'm good at :S