# Chrome keydown events have wrong keyCode

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

When I create html pages that log keydown events I get incorrect keyCode values, yet I can verify hosted sites have the correct keyCodes, so it's not globally broken.

Here's an example page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.body.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
        console.log("KEYDOWN", event)
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I set that up as test.html and host it locally using a simple static server (`static-server .` for me) and then press lower case "e", I get an event with a `keyCode` of 69, which corresponds to capital "E" (`String.fromCharCode(69) == 'E'`). Why is it not 101, the keyCode for "e"?

When I visit hosted sites that handle keypress events Chrome is emitting keyCode 101, so it seems like there's some setting or configuration that I'm missing.

Comment: You should check the property `ShiftKey` if it's true or not

Comment: Thanks Zohir, I can definitely check to see if shiftKey is true and then add 32 to the code if not, but then when I hit space I get "@". So then I'd have to filter for only characters to apply to, etc. Just wondering why it's happening in the first place

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with javascript onkeydown - event.which give characters in upper case only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905204/issue-with-javascript-onkeydown-event-which-give-characters-in-upper-case-only)

Comment: Note [`keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) is depreciated, and the [value is not compatible between browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode#Value_of_keyCode). If you want to get wither or not a capital letter was typed vs a lowercase use the [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) property if available. Otherwise check the state of the keys like Shift

Comment: Oh yes my mistake, since i got this to work one time i didn't actually look what event you were using, refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9905293/7148391)