# How to call the onclick function after pressing Enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a chat web application, to send a message, there's an `input type="text"` and an `input type="button"`, using a function in JavaScript, I managed to work it out by adding `onclick="sendMessage()"` as an attribute for the `input button`, but I need to click on it, but I want it to work like any chat messengers or apps, the client writes something down and hits ENTER key, this could work if I used a `<form onsubmit="sendMessage()">` and `input type="submit"` but then the page will refresh, How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 <form onsubmit="sendMessage();return false">
```

That prevents the default action of sending a request to the server.

Answer (score 3):

This in-case you want also diable the enter button from Posting to server and execute the Js script.

```
<input type="text" id="txtSearch" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13)
{document.getElementById('btnSearch').click(); return false;}"/>
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="doSomething();"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to hook into the onkeypress/up/down events for the textbox.
This should get you started:
[Enter key press event in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905222/javascriptenter-key-press-event)

Comment: and also, using snowball's answer to cancel the event after you handle it, add "return false;".

Answer (score 2):

Use onkeydown() (or keyPress or keyUp, depending on semantics) instead of on click - this will get you an event with the event.keyCode you want - 13 - and you can easily submit using an AJAX request (i.e. XMLHttpRequest)

Simple Code: - raw Javascript, Don't need JQuery:

```
<html>
<script>
function keyPress(e)
{
if (!e) e = window.event; // needed for cross browser compatibility
alert(e.keyCode); // You want 13 here , so 
 // if (e.keyCode == 13)
 //  etc..

// return true; or false, if you want to cancel event

}
</script>
<body>
<input type="text" onkeydown="keyPress()" size="20"/>xx

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks ;) You got whats in my mind after I said "Chat web app" :P