# detect when form was submitted with enter

Tags: html

I use this to detect enter:

```
<input type="submit" name=hiddenbutton value=enter style="display: none">
```

When this is placed before all other form elements, then I get the appropriate `$_REQUEST[hiddenbutton]`when enter was used to submit the form.

Except with Chrome and other Webkit-based browsers, which don't activate the first button when enter is pressed.

Is there a way to make it work on all browsers? (preferably with as little JavaScript as possible)

Comment: If you need to detect how exactly the form was submitted you are most likely doing something wrong. What is the problem you are trying to solve with this detection?

Comment: Check how to detect event on ENTER key press here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905222/enter-key-press-event-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend adding a focus listener to make sure the user is not justdoing something completely different like typing in a word document, because some browsers will detect key clicks without focus