# call javascript function on ENTER key press?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to scroll down the page using javascript.

I have this code which works fine if if i use `javascript:pageScroll()` in a link or button:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript">
function pageScroll() {
        window.scrollBy(0,50); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
        scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',100); // scrolls every 100 milliseconds
}
</SCRIPT>
```

but i need to find out how i can call the pageScroll() function if the user presses enter on their keyboard?

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: add an `onkeydown` event? I really am not sure what you are asking, did you try anything?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905222/enter-key-press-event-in-javascript - stackoverflow is not supposed to be a google replacement?

Answer (score 8):

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery, you might be interested in `.keypress()`. Here: http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Also you could have easily avoided this question by doing a simple Google search.