# Submit form data both on clicking enter and hitting the submit button from a Bootstrap modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Here's my form that's in my modal window:

I have no close button and I have disabled the window from closing on pressing esc. I want to be able to submit the form data on pressing submit or on pressing the enter key.

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Enter your Credentials</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="login-form" class="form-horizontal" accept-charset="UTF-8"  data-remote="true"">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value=""  placeholder="Email">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="password" id="passwd" name="passwd" value="" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                    </label>
                    <input type="submit"  id="login" value="Login"class="btn btn-primary" />

                </div>
            </div>
        </form>          
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the script I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});

function submitLogin() {
    $.ajax({
        url:"login_mysql.php",
        type:'POST',
        dataType:"json",
        data: $("#login-form").serialize()
    }).done(function(data){
        //do something
    });
}

$('#passwd').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == '13') {
        submitLogin();
    }
});

$('#login').click(function(){
    submitLogin();
});
```

On pressing enter after keying in my password or clicking on the submit button the same page reloads and the ajax script does not run. Could someone tell me if my script is clashing with the default settings of my modal window?

Comment: change type="submit" from your login button to type="button"

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Listen to form `submit` event - it gets triggered by both enter and click events.

**Markup**

```
<form id="yourForm">
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <input type="password" name="password">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$('#yourForm').submit(function(event){

  // prevent default browser behaviour
  event.preventDefault();

  //do stuff with your form here
  ...

});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Change type="submit" from your login button to type="button".

EDIT:
2. Try removing data-keyboard="false".

Comment: the modal submits data on clicking the button but not on hitting the enter key.

Answer (score 0):

I have done that where the submit form would open in modal dialog box and, after that, submit the whole entry in the fields. If you click on submit button, entry would done on the database and instantly the page is redirected to same page with new data. There is no need to refresh to see the recent entered data.
Hope this helps.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">ADD CONTENT</button>
<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Please Add Content</h4>
        </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form role="form" action="" method="POST">
          <!-- YOUR HTML FORM GOES HERE--->
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"id="sub" onclick="SUBMISSION()" >Submit </button>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    SUBMISSION();
  }
  function SUBMISSION()
  {
    // UR CONNECTION ESTABLISHMENT CODE GOES HERE
    // SQL QUERY FOR INSERTION IN FIELDS

    echo"<script type=\"text/javascript\">
      document.location.href='http://localhost/dict/pages/YOURPAGE.php';
    </script>";

    $conn->CLOSE();
  }
?>

        </div>                      
       </div>
     <!-- /.modal-content -->
     </div>
   <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
   <!-- /.panel-body -->
   </div>
   <!-- /.panel -->
 </div>
 <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer a little more? It's hard to follow what you've written here.

Comment: yaa ofcourse..but it is not so hard to understand.     i have used bootstrap modal to open the submit form and after submit click button u can see instantly filled data. first i defined button following the modal box div and in the modal body i defined the form which is going to be shown on modalbox after clicking on "add content button"

Comment: after filling all the data u click on submit button and then in the  execution of SUBMISSION()  first data will save in database and then using document.location.href u will redirect to datatable page where u can see the recent filled data. so simple to execute it super

Comment: in simple i defined all the form field in modal body  and submission is executed in php as u can see it