# Javascript will not redirect the form to the specified file path (or URL), with the dual option of pressing return key, or clicking submit button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, redirect, passwords

I am a beginner, and I have researched for a week now on this roadblock. I have tried many options to make this simple code work. **The goal is to enter a password, then press enter OR click submit button**, then redirect the page to the specified URL or file path. Everything else I have tried seems to blank out a function like pressing enter won't work anymore, or the next option will redirect but even when the password is wrong, or the next idea doesn't pop up the alert for wrong password; examples:

1. Tried using input type="button" with onclick="2ndFunction" and having that 2nd function trigger the onSubmit() function..
2. Tried using both input type="button" AND input type="submit" as a separate form beneath the input type="password" form. With both, I tried doing onClick or onSubmit functions to check the password.
3. form action="url.blah" will redirect the page to url.blah even if you get the password wrong; it will do password check, wronggg, then redirect. Form action="#" is pretty much obsolete or not necessary, and does the same thing as well.
4. form method="post" or "get" doesnt do anything for this function, besides send the typed-in password somewhere into the unknown space/ server side/ current url.. unless i am implementing this wrong..

There must be a simple fix, or something simple I am missing here that I can add to make this all come together. Explaining something in very simple terms means you understand it well. I also understand security concerns, and **security is NOT a concern for this function**. I would greatly appreciate some help!!! Here is what I am working with (using notepad), in very simple format:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
     function onSubmit() 
    {if (document.getElementById('password').value == '1234')
    {window.location.href = "https://www.google.com"; }else
        { alert('WRONGGG');}
    }
</script>
<form>
  <div>
  <label>Enter your passcode</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
  </div> 
<input type="submit" value="Enter" id="button" onclick="return
 (onSubmit())"/>   
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please read the SO guidelines [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), specifically: "Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague". There is a lot of strife and apology described here, but SO is concerned only with the **technical problem**.

Comment: Regarding _Everything else I have tried seems to […] or […] or […]_ — these are _potentially useful details_, and you should write down each change you tried, and what results that change produced.

Comment: Generally this problem is solved by including the [JQuery](https://jquery.com/download/) library, and using its [`submit()`](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) function upon your `form`. I am marking this question as a duplicate of a _JQuery form submission_ question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submit form data both on clicking enter and hitting the submit button from a Bootstrap modal window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19297520/submit-form-data-both-on-clicking-enter-and-hitting-the-submit-button-from-a-boo)

Comment: Thank you for the delightful feedback, but I wouldnt be here if I could find the answer explained easily enough to understand. My question is 'how do I get the page to redirect after validating the password function,' whereas that "bootstrap modal window" question is only asking how to use the enter key and/or button click to submit the form. Yes, coincidence that I would also like both the enter key and button click to redirect, however that other question does not explain my problem with the javascript not redirecting after the password validation/ form submission.

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot simpler then you think. It's actually a function in `html` itself already.

`<form method="post" action="yourfile.php">`

Make that your opening tag, and set the file you want it to go to. In this case it will go to the file `yourfile.php` on submit.

In that file, you can check if the `password` is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify in in action attribute of form like.
`<form action="/url" method="post">`
or you should write event handlers for both `keyboard and mouseclick`

If you want to validate before sending to url you should use the second method