# How can I run script when a url loads?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

When I access http://www.facebook.com/ from my browser, I want to execute a script which fills the login field and a click event on the login button so that I don't need to type email/password.

my code

```
(function() {
    document.getElementById('email').value = "abc@zyx.com"; 
    document.getElementById('pass').value = "12345678"; 
    document.getElementById('login_form').submit(); 
})();
```

Comment: [This might help you. Your question seems related to this already answered one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19297520/submit-form-data-both-on-clicking-enter-and-hitting-the-submit-button-from-a-boo)

Comment: you need to create a browser extension,or you can write a temper monkey script

Comment: @parthu_panther give me some clue how it can be done suppose I've accessed the facebook url.

Comment: @FastSnail I wrote an iffe and tried to access the fields and form submit on [link](http://facebook.com) and executed it through js console, and but it didn't work. I'm trying to get that right first

Comment: @negi.Shubham that's not hard.can you share your script so we can find the problem.

Comment: '(function() {
 document.getElementById('email').value = "abc@zyx.com";
 document.getElementById('pass').value = "12345678";
 document.getElementById('login_form').submit();
})();'

Comment: It was straight so I just accessed the fields that needs to be filled and just submitted the form.

Comment: @negi.Shubham i'm confused your code work fine?

Comment: no it didn't worked, nothing happens when I try to attach these codes with the page through inspector. Could you help me show some code..