# Change color of li class with javascript when keyboard key is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a keyboard with HTML and CSS, and I'm trying to make the keys "glow" with a different background-color when the same key is pressed on the keyboard (the real-life keyboard that is).

It looks something like this:

```
<div id="keyboard">
<ul class="row">
<li class="letter">Q</li>
<li class="letter">W</li>
.
.
.
</ul>
</div>
```

And i have the following javascript code:

```
$('#keyboard .letter').keydown(function() {
$(this).addClass('red');
}).keyup(function() {
$(this).removeClass('red');
});
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: The color doesn't change when I press a key

Comment: How can you press a key there? It's not an input field?

Comment: I'm just trying to make the keys "glow" when pressing them on my keyboard, without an input field.. Is it possible?

Comment: You need to use key event codes.  Look at [this list](http://www.webonweboff.com/tips/js/event_key_codes.aspx) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905222/enter-key-press-event-in-javascript) to help you tremendously.

Comment: How does the page know you're pressing a key?

Comment: Do you mean that if the user presses a certain character, that character should glow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This worked for me:

**HTML**

```
<div id="keyboard">
    <ul class="row">
        <li class="letter" id="q">Q</li>
        <li class="letter" id="w">W</li>. . .</ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
    
    var which_letter = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    $('#'+which_letter+'').addClass('red');

});

$(document).keyup(function(){
    $(".letter").removeClass('red');
});
```

**CSS**

```
 .red { color:#f00; }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4sCw9/1/)

## Note

If you would like the letter to glow no matter if he/she presses 'X' or 'x', change:

```
var which_letter = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
```

to:

```
var which_letter = String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase();
```

Otherwise the user must press exactly the value of the letter's `id`.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see you are using jQuery. So it is easy to trigger key events like this one for example:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 50; // Your code value here
$("input").trigger(e);
```

Additionally, if you want to use clicks on your keyboard then you must use input type of field.