# html form without submit button and anchor link onclick redirect with input value

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to redirect people like this: `example.com/search/[search+text]`

html source code:

```
<form name="menu_search" method="get" onsubmit="window.location.href = 'http://www.col3negmovie.com/search/'+this.q.value+''; return false;" >
    <input name="q" id="videoSearch" />
</form>
```

this is the anchor link :

```
<a href="./#" onclick="document.menu_search.submit(); window.location.href='http://www.col3negmovie.com/search/'+this.q.value+''; return false;">Search</a>
```

onclick doesn't work, how could i fix this?

```
onclick="document.menu_search.submit();
window.location.href='http://www.col3negmovie.com/search/'+this.q.value+'';
return false;"
```

Comment: Try removing this line `document.menu_search.submit(); `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form:

```
<form name="menu_search" method="get" onsubmit="window.location.href = 'http://www.col3negmovie.com/search/'+document.getElementsByName('q')[0].value+''; return false;" >
<input name="q" id="videoSearch" />
</form>
```

Anchor tag:

```
<a href="./#" onclick="document.getElementsByName('menu_search')[0].submit(); return false;">Search</a>
```

---

Or without the `<form>` tag (which makes it less confusing):

```
<input name="q" id="videoSearch" />
<a href="./#" onclick="window.location.href = 'http://www.col3negmovie.com/search/' + document.getElementById('videoSearch').value;">Search</a>
```

To do the same when 'Enter' is pressed:

```
document.getElementById("videoSearch").onkeyup = function() {
if (this.event.keyCode == 13 || this.event.which == 13)
    //Enter was pressed, handle it here
    window.location.href = 'http://www.col3negmovie.com/search/' + document.getElementById('videoSearch').value;
}
}
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: @user3501407 This is confusing ... does it work or not?

Comment: Actually in my opinion, the `<form>` tag is unneccessary

Comment: but somepeoples not click that link only just enter so work ?

Comment: how to add this friend ?

Comment: Add this between you `<script>` tags

Comment: Put the script tags in the body, not the head. Dont need head.

Comment: @user3501407 Sorry but not free. You might want to see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905222/enter-key-press-event-in-javascript) link.

Comment: i think want to somechange with anchor tag know?

Comment: if have some problem now you can check