# Trigger event when i hit enter button in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code

```
$("body").on("click", "#pp_full_res button[name^=calc_shipping]", function () {})
```

Which works perfectly when I click on `button.`

I have another `textbox` which has id `myid`. I want trigger above same function when someone hit `enter` button in `textbox.`

How can i achieve this?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905222/enter-key-press-event-in-javascript

Comment: @latha12b $("body").on("click", "#pp_full_res button[name^=calc_shipping]", function () {
  
 //mycode
 
  });

Answer (score 2):

like so:

```
$("body").on("click", "#pp_full_res button[name^=calc_shipping]", myWorkingFunction);
$("textarea#myid").on('keyup', checkEnter);


function checkEnter(e) {
    if (e.keyCode==13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        myWorkingFunction();
    }
}
```

**Notice**: move your working function to an external function so you can call it from different places..