# How to find whether enter key is pressed in javascript

Tags: javascript

Sample Code that I'm using:

```
e.keyCode == 13 if (e.which==13) { e.preventDefault(); }
```

Is any idea apart from this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enter key press event in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905222/enter-key-press-event-in-javascript)

Comment: it would only be a duplicate of the mentioned question if this one also applies to forms, which the op didn't specify if it was or not. (Though I assume it is because of the use of preventDefault, but that's just a guess.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var variablename= (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
     if(code == 13) { //keycode of Enter key
       alert('enter key pressed');
     }
```

if you are using jquery

```
$('input[type=text]').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```