# How can I wire up a button on my page so that it is clicked when a user presses enter?

Tags: angularjs

I have many buttons on my page but none are inside a form. I already assigned one button and changed its color so it shows as a bootstrap primary button.

How can I make it so that when a user is on the page and they click enter then the button click event for that button is called?

Comment: Looks like this has what you need, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905222/enter-key-press-event-in-javascript

Comment: use `ng-enter` wouldn't be a bad idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about what you are asking; but you can do the following, if you have a controller with the function add() attached to the scope:

```
<form ng-submit="add()">
  <input type="text" ng-model="myModel">
  <input type="submit" value="Add"/>
</form>
```

The above adds the value entered in the input to the model.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a `<form ...>` around your elements. Because if you rely on a custom keypress detector, and you have more than one button, it will activate all of them. The `<form ...>` dictates which button is to be submitted when a user is in a particular input field and hits Enter.

Your form doesn't even need to have an `action="..."` or `method="..."`. You could just as well use `ng-submit="yourFormParser()"`.

Comment: Can you give an example so I can see what you mean. Would it be okay to just put a dive with ng-form ?

Comment: @Alan Sorry I never responded to you, I don't visit here frequently. But the example would like exactly as user3681587 suggested.

Answer (score 0):

ng-submit will not useful to you, because your form submit event is different.

The only option remains is, you can take use of `ng-enter` directive, but you should manually bind it wherever you want. I believe this is last option.

`ng-enter="myEvent()"`

**HTML**

```
<input type="text/url/email/number/checkbox/radio" ng-model="test" ng-enter="myEvent()"/>
```

Hope this could help you, Thanks.