# Modify Search Widget Value Before Searching for Results

Tags: javascript, arcgis, esri

I've a [Search](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/search-amd.html) widget on my map. What I'm trying to do is when a user types, let's say, `1215 Bourboun St`, I want to append `Sacramento, US` to that value so that **very precised** results are returned back.

I've looked at the documentation and found a `search-results` event, which basically lets me play around with the **returned** results. But is there an event which I can subscribe to which takes place just before a search is done? This will enable me to modify the search value before initiating a search.

My code is as follows:

```
map = new Map("mapDiv", {
    center: [xyz, abc],
    zoom: 10,
    basemap: "streets"
});

var search = new Search({
   map: map       
}, dom.byId("search"));
search.startup();
search.on("search-results", populateHiddenField);
.
.
. 
// some irrelevant code
```

**UPDATE**

Using Gary's suggestion, I created a fiddle to let you experts help me out on this one.

**Case Scenario:**: If you start typing `1215`, you'll notice that it returns result from all over the world and not just Sacramento even though I've extended the `Search` class per Gary's suggestion. Is there a way that I can restrict the autosuggestions to Sacramento alone?

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/y2f2sha6/)

Comment: Why don't you [capture the enter key with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/905233)?

Comment: Wouldn't using a pre-defined event be better instead of using custom code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** the question was edited to enable suggestions instead of disabling them, and I have updated my answer accordingly. Handling suggestions is as simple as overriding the `suggest` method in exactly the same way as the `search` method.

---

Create a new class that extends `Search` and override the `search` function.

```
map = new Map("mapDiv", {
    center: [xyz, abc],
    zoom: 10,
    basemap: "streets"
});

//Define new class that inherits from Search
var MySearch = declare(Search, {
    //Override the search method
    search: function () {
        var originalValue = this.value;
        this.set("value", this.value + ", Sacramento, CA");
        var retVal = this.inherited(arguments);
        this.set("value", originalValue);
        return retVal;
    }

    //Override the suggest method
    suggest: function () {
        var originalValue = this.value;
        this.set("value", this.value + ", Sacramento, CA");
        var retVal = this.inherited(arguments);
        this.set("value", originalValue);
        return retVal;
    }
});           

var search = new MySearch({
    map: map,
    enableSuggestionsMenu:true,
    enableSuggestions:true,
    autoSelect:true,
    autoNavigate:true
}, dom.byId("search"));
search.startup();
search.on("search-results", populateHiddenField);
```

You'll need to include `"dojo/_base/declare"` in your `require` list.

See http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/declare/ for more details on extending a Dojo class.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this out and let you know, not at my desk right now

Comment: Hi, unfortunately it didn't work. I added a fiddle to my first post in case you wanna see it in action

Comment: I just updated the answer to handle the edited question.

Comment: Sorry about the question change. It does work indeed. +1 and accepted

Comment: No worries. Sometimes we don't realize exactly which question we meant to ask until we get some answers. :-)