# JavaScript: Pressing enter on a text input invoking a function

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://codepen.io/abdulahhamzic/pen/YqMQwB

How do I make it so that when I press enter on a text input, it calls a function? I tried using this:

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="clickPress()">
```

But the problem is I only want to press enter to call that function, not press any key. How do I achieve that?

2022 Update: `onkeypress` is deprecated.
You can use `onKeyDown` instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enter key press event in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905222/enter-key-press-event-in-javascript)

Comment: If you wrap your input in a form, and give the form a submit button you can listen to the submit event, which is a much better way to handle such things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a form instead (the submit event only runs once instead of every key press):

```js
// Attach the event handler to the form element
document.querySelector('.js-form')?.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert(e.currentTarget.myText.value);
});
```

```html
<form class="js-form">
  <input type="text" name="myText">
</form>
```

Answer (score 28):

What you'd want to do is check whether the event's key is the enter key:

In your html, add the event argument

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="clickPress(event)">
```

And in your handler, add an event parameter

```
function clickPress(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

---

### 2022 Update: `event.keyCode` is deprecated on many browsers.

You should do this now:

```
function clickPress(event) {
    if (event.key == "Enter") {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: The HTML has to be changed to `onkeypress="clickPress(event)"` for this to work.

Comment: `<input type="text" onkeypress="clickPress(e)">` wont work, you'd need to put `event` as the argument.

Comment: But how do I make it so that both pressing enter and clicking on submit provoke the function?

Comment: @Daan and 4castle are right, so I adjusted that part of the code.

Comment: @Абдулах Хамзиќ that's actually a separate question, but the answer is very similar: add onclick="doSomething()" and have the "// do something" in my answer make use of the function doSomething

Comment: Note: Inline JS like the `onkeypress="clickPress(event)"` part of this answer is often discouraged by current web standards (it is mixing content and functionality concerns). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript#Separation_of_behavior_from_markup for more information

Comment: @BDawg that's true, if we ignore e.g. ReactJS and (fundamentally) AngularJS. Another important thing to note is that old-school inline JavaScript tended to involve heaps of it, while the above approach essentially only binds an event to a function.

Comment: @AlainVanHout - I was thinking it was true regardless of those two frameworks. This answer appears to be a vanilla HTML/JS solution, not a React or Angular one (which I believe have a different set of concerns/standards).

Comment: @AlainVanHout - Also, though I certainly agree that a simple function call is better than putting the entire function inline, the `clickPress()` function is now polluting the global namespace - creating more opportunities for a front end maintenance problem to appear.

Comment: Up-voting because you didn't lame out and force dump 70KB of useless frameworks on the client because you actually knew how to answer the question.

Comment: I just had an issue with this in Firefox and then it showed up in Chrome, while writing my console window in a browser (html5/canvas) http://raddev.us/console/console.htm.  I think you'll find that you need to handle the key like:
if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.keyCode == 'Enter')  IE seems to get the int but Chrome and Firefox get the string.

Answer (score 1):

The Enter button has a keyCode of 13, so you can use the [keypress event](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/) using jQuery

```
$("input").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        alert("Enter was pressed");
     }
});
```

or, in pure javascript:

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="clickPress(event)">

function clickPress(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the event's `keycode` and test if it's `enter` (`keycode 13`)

```
<script>
    function clickPress(e){
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        // Enter was pressed
        alert("enter");
    }
  }
</script>

<input type="text" onkeypress="clickPress(event)" />
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jejhod2h/3/)

Answer (score 0):

There could be several "better" ways to do what you want to do but just for the sake of simplicity, you could do this:

```
<input type="text" id="txt">
```

Instead of listening to the `onkeypress` you could attach an event listener within the `<script></script>` tags and do this:

```
var myText = document.getElementById("txt");
myText.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        //The keycode for enter key is 13
        alert(e.target.value);
    }
});
```

And yeah this is definitely a duplicate question.