# How to get press key "Enter" in form with no input or input text disable

Tags: javascript

How to get press key "Enter" in form with no input or input text disable.
I want to get input key "Enter" to make some code change but don't know how to do this.

Comment: You're going to have to be a lot clearer than this ?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905222/enter-key-press-event-in-javascript

Comment: what do you mean by no input or input text disable?

Comment: If you're not going to clarify the question, please delete it.

Answer (score -1):

```
someFocusedElement.onkeypress = function (event) {
    if (event.key=="Enter")
        alert('You pressed Enter!')
}
```