# How to avoid refreshing page with event onkeypress ENTER (keyCode == 13)?

Tags: javascript

I need to send form input to js function after keypress <kbd>enter</kbd>

Following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/905233/6827096 but below code refreshing page after pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>.

```
#.html
<script src="chat.js'"></script>
<input  onkeypress="return sendChatMessage(event)">

#chat.js
function sendChatMessage(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        console.log("e.keyCode == 13");   //never reachable
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

How to avoid refreshing page with event onkeypress ENTER (keyCode == 13) ?

Function `sendChatMessage` is visible in browser console with page loaded.

Comment: Is input inside a form? I don't see how pressing enter would refresh the page. If it is, consider stopping form submission first.

Comment: Try with the onKeyup event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your input is within `<form>` element, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> will try to submit the form. Try to add `preventDefault()` in your `sendChatMessage()`:

```
function sendChatMessage(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();  // this should prevent default action
        console.log("e.keyCode == 13");   //never reachable
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `e.preventDefault();` to your function sendChatMessage, **it is going to prevent link from opening**. Your code will look like this:

```
function sendChatMessage(e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
e.preventDefault();  // add  this line of code.
        console.log("e.keyCode == 13");   //never reachable
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: preventDefault() is the answer, (user @errata was 4 min faster). Thanks for reply.

Comment: That's completely okay.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use both [e.which](https://api.jquery.com/event.which/) and e.keyCode:

```
function sendChatMessage(e) {
    if (e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("e.keyCode == 13"); 
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```