# Form enter key and button click do different things

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm finding that when I submit my form by pressing the enter key, the page refreshes (because my form doesn't specify an action), but if I click the button, it executes the jQuery.

How can I make an enter key press execute the jQuery as well?

Here's my code:

```
<form id="signup-form">
    <input type="text" id="text-input-splash" class="text-input" placeholder="Enter your email"><button type="button" id="submit-input-splash">Sign me up</button>
</form>
<p id="validation-message"></p>
<p>100% private and free. No spam. One-click unsubscribe.</p>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit-input-splash").click(function() {
            // import email variable
            var email = $("#text-input-splash").val();
            $.post("signup.php", {email: email}, function(data){
                $("#validation-message").text(data).addClass("error-text");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: read please about $("#signup-form").submit();

Comment: onkeydown event may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905222/enter-key-press-event-in-javascript

Comment: track submit event on form (trigger right before sending form to server)

Comment: In the perfect old fashion way of pure javascript, enter key do what `action` inside form tag prescribes. Button do whatever script may be associate with it. Using fancy libraries such jQuery... who knows what's happening :D Keep rowing saylor.

Comment: Not a `PHP` issue though - purely `HTML`/`JS` (`jQuery`) (for the tags)

Comment: @CD001 Right; and I've edited the post. The OP should have done something about your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To both solve the issue and improve your logic, change your button to a `type="submit"` and hook the event handler to the `submit` event of the form. Try this:

```
<form id="signup-form">
  <input type="text" id="text-input-splash" class="text-input" placeholder="Enter your email">
  <button type="submit" id="submit-input-splash">Sign me up</button>
</form>
<p id="validation-message"></p>
<p>100% private and free. No spam. One-click unsubscribe.</p>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#signup-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = $("#text-input-splash").val();
    $.post("signup.php", { email: email }, function(data) {
      $("#validation-message").text(data).addClass("error-text");
    });
  });
});
```