# How to detect if enter key is pressed in JS

Tags: javascript

I need to execute a JavaScript function when the enter key is pressed, i tried `KeyCode` but I found out it's deprecated,I can't do it in JQuery because i'm executing it at the end of the code, so it would be too late because someone could press enter before JQuery execution. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enter key press event in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905222/enter-key-press-event-in-javascript)

Comment: The following code will work fine. 

    onkeydown="javascript:if ((event.which && event.which == 13)) { alert('Enter Key pressed');}"

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way:

```js
document.onkeypress = function (e) {
 if (e.keyCode == 13) alert("Enter");
};
```