# Moving through jQuery Autocomplete Widget with ENTER not mouse down and mouse up press

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using JQuery autocomplete widget. Moving through the autocomplete list is with arrow up and arrow down. I want that the user can move through with ENTER. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905222/enter-key-press-event-in-javascript