# Click event triggered by enter key

Tags: javascript, html, click

I've created in Javascript a click event on a `<button type="submit">` in a `form` element. This event is also triggered when I press the enter key. Is this default html behavior?

Comment: it is default html behaviour for `form` element

Comment: if you press Enter in the textbox or input field  of the following <form> it will submit a search query , so if you dont want to trigger that button , change the type of button to `button` like this `<button type="button">`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent form submission on Enter key press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905222/prevent-form-submission-on-enter-key-press)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input type=submit>` in the form gets the automatic Enter Key behavior. This is known as an implicit form submission.